# Problems installing Minecraft mod "Spartan Weaponry" 1.16.5 on MacBook Pro

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge, minecraft-fabric

I'm trying to install a Minecraft mod on my Mac called "Spartan Weaponry". It downloads a jar file onto my computer. When I double click the file, it seems to be opening up, but I can't see the unzipped folder on my computer.

I am also unable to put the mod into my Minecraft and every time it asks me to install Curseforge, but when I re-install it, nothing happens. Any suggestions?

The version is a MacOS Big Sur Version 11.2.2, MacBook Pro

Edit: Yes, I do have the latest version of JDK installed

Answer (score -1):

Stackoverflow is for coding related problems, however I will answer your question.
Do not double click this file. Instead, follow these steps:

1. Open Minecraft (with forge installed)
2. Select Mods from the title screen.
3. Open the mods folder
4. Move the `.jar` file to the mods folder.

"*Edit: Yes, I do have the latest version of JDK installed*"
You don't need JDK, just get Java.

**I recommend posting this here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/**

*(I don't have enough reputation to flag this post for it to be moved.)*

Comment: The way my Minecraft works is that I have to open up "Options" then go to "Resource Packs..." and then open up "Open Pack Folder" in order to see my mods, and even when I put the mods there they don't open

Comment: @NotSteve5 It seems you don't have Forge installed then. All Forge clients will have a mods option.

Comment: I already had the latest Forge version, Mac version, and the latest version of Minecraft installed.

Comment: @NotSteve5 Make sure you are booting into your forge installation in Minecraft launcher.